# why false if will execute?

Tags: java, if-statement

Here is a code snippet from `SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject` in WSO2 `org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso` package.

```
if (argLength != 1 || !(args[0] instanceof String)) {
    String errorMsg = "Invalid argument. SAML response is missing.";
    log.error(errorMsg);
    throw new ScriptException(errorMsg);
}
```

when I was debugging this I saw even though this if expression evaluate to false, ScriptException will execute. anyone has explanation for that?

**EDIT**

The reason was I was debugging in wrong jar in eclipse IDE. server jar version is different was from the jar version I was debugging. even though IDE shows debug was on that line. actually debug was outside of if block

Comment: What is "this expression"? Do you know how if statements work? Do you know how boolean operators work? Can you explain what things you do understand so we don't have to explain 20% of Java in the hopes of catching the thing you don't? What were the arguments when you were debugging? Those are all reasons for the downvote.

Comment: command line is always as `string`

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm guessing that it's because it can't execute if the expression evaluates to false. Maybe you're confused by the '!'?

Comment: Well. What if `argLength == 1 && args[0] is of type String`?. Just saying.

Comment: @djechlin: if "if" statement evaluate to true code inside it will execute. otherwise it will not. but eventhough this if expression evaluate to false the code inside it will execute. that is wierd. isn't it?

Comment: @lakshman try put `System.out.print(argLength != 1 || !(args[0] instanceof String))` inside the `if` statement. if the output is `false` then I upvote your question 1000x

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: yes. good point. I will do that way. thanks.

Comment: I don't even know how to explain your logic to you. You wrote a contradiction then called it "weird" instead of saying "Oh! I contradicted myself now! One of my premises must be wrong, I will go find out which before asking about it on StackOverflow." Downvote stands, good night.

Comment: @djechlin: yes.good point. one of my premises must be wrong. is there anyway to delete this question to find out this myself?

Comment: Not after it has an answer (which basically says what you just said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be misinterpreting what you saw in debug. If the complete logical expression in the if() evaluates to false, then the code inside the brackets shown will not execute. Perhaps the exception was thrown from elsewhere, or else the complete logical expression actually evaluated to true.